# Desinstalar wamp por completo

Tags: wamp, server

tengo varios problemas con wamp server y creo que es mejor desinstalarlo por completo y volver a instalarlo. ¿Pero cómo lo puedo desinstalar por completo, alguien sabe?

Comment: Bienvenido @AlejandroMejia a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), favoreciendo así tus chances de obtener una buena recepción por parte de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Hola existen varias formas desintalar wamp:

- Desde Panel de control -> desintalar programas
- Con un programa   llamado CCleaner
- Desde el directorio donde se encuenta wamp instalado ejecutas el
  unistaller o el unis000.exe
- Puedes restaurar tu sistema a un punto anterior en donde no se
  encontraba wamp    instalado en tu equipo
- Con tu antivirus
- Reinstalando wamp para tener la opcion de desintalarlo
- Desde regedit buscando el registro
  "KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
  le das doble clic a UninstallString y copias el valor que te da, luego Tecla Windows + R y copias el valor de Unistall.